# jQuery "Cannot read property 'defaultView' of undefined" error

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using jQuery to post a form field to a PHP file that simply returns 1/0 depending on whether it worked or not...

Extract of the code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "ajax/save_text.php", //Relative?!?
    //PHP Script
    type: "POST",
    //Use post
    data: 'test=' + $(this).val(),
    datatype: 'text',
    //Pass value       
    cache: false,
    //Do not cache the page
    success: function(html) {
        if (html == 1) {
            $(this).hide().siblings('span').html($(this).value).show();
                    alert("awesome!");
        } else alert('It didn\'t work!');
    },
    //Error
    error: function() {
        alert("Another type of error");
    }
});
```

However everytime it is successful (html == 1) the console throws up the error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaultView' of undefined"

and the alert never happens...?

Google doesn't seem to have much info on this error and jQuery, who knows the cause?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It's because `this` isn't what you were dealing with before, it's now tha `ajax` jQuery object, add the [`context` option of `$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) like this:

```
$.ajax({
  context: this,
  url: "ajax/save_text.php",
  ...
```

This way `this` inside your callbacks refers to the same `this` as when you're calling [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).  Alternatively, just hold onto a reference to `this` in a separate variable.

Also, you'll need to adjust `$(this).value`, you probably meant `this.value` or `$(this).val()`.

Comment: @Pez - not silly at all, I think it's rather counter-intuitive as well that this isn't the *default* context behavior.

Comment: Yeah, this just bit me, too, after a bit of refactoring. Thanks for the answer. :)

Comment: Agree here, counter-intuitive, I just fell into the trap too and I've been using JavaScript for 8 years!