# Submit multiple forms with jQuery php mysql

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I have any page for answer/question. i retrieve list of question for admin. admin see this. now i need to send answer to each question. so i for each question put `textarea` and form with post action. now i need to when send answer of question message, if send message to external php files = true;  of message(ID) remove(jquery slideup effect). for this i have jquery submit form code ( without refresh page ) but I have big problem. this worked ONLY with one form ! and not worked for all list form ( question + answer form ) . how to worked my code for multiple form ? I chose the right way?

html code :

```
<form action="insert.php?id=42" id="forms" method="POST" name="form">
<div id="box">
<div class="messagequestion"></div>
<div class="messagereply"><textarea></textarea><input type="submit" class="submit" name="submit" value="submit"></div>
</div>
</form>
<form action="insert.php?id=45" id="forms" method="POST" name="form">
<div id="box">
<div class="messagequestion"></div>
<div class="messagereply"><textarea></textarea><input type="submit" class="submit" name="submit" value="submit"></div>
</div>
</form>
<form action="insert.php?id=48" id="forms" method="POST" name="form">
<div id="box">
<div class="messagequestion"></div>
<div class="messagereply"><textarea></textarea><input type="submit" class="submit" name="submit" value="submit"></div>
</div>
</form>
<form action="insert.php?id=50" id="forms" method="POST" name="form">
<div id="box">
<div class="messagequestion"></div>
<div class="messagereply"><textarea></textarea><input type="submit" class="submit" name="submit" value="submit"></div>
</div>
</form>
```

Thanks

Comment: Don't use same `id` for multiple Objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your major issue is probably that you are trying to reuse ids. All the forms have the id of `"forms"` and you are also sharing the id `"box"`.

All ids should uniquely identify an element. Use a class when you need to classify an element. I'd recommend you change `id="forms"` on all the forms to `class="reply_form"` and then also change `id="box"` on all the divs to `class="reply_box"`. Then change styles set for #forms and #box to those set for .reply_form and .reply instead.

EDIT - tweaks made in jsfiddle after some discussion with the OP.

http://jsfiddle.net/gvnfg/5/

Comment: i change this for each '<textarea></textarea>' ! http://jsfiddle.net/gvnfg/3/ after click to submit i see dialog box but after click ok i see loop of dialog box for other ID . this is big problem.

Comment: im Confused in jsfiddle worked but in my localhost not work :(

Comment: after click i didnt see alert dialog box ! if action of form empty refresh page ! if action to axternal page e.x ( insert.php?id=42) i see this page /insert.php?id=42 . alert box not work! sorry i dont have access for join chat

Comment: There are some strange characters in the file - to me they appear as "â~@~K". They appear in three places (twice at end of the script). Once I removed those, the code worked fine for me.

Comment: with alert box worked now ! but with url not remove comments box (class)! please see online demo : http://stacktest.byethost8.com/demo.php

Comment: It is because [`this` in `$(this).slideUp(1000);`, which originally held the form element, is replaced with the jQuery ajax object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936211/jquery-cannot-read-property-defaultview-of-undefined-error). To remedy this you can either set the form element to a var before the ajax call and then use that var (so add `var form_element = this;` before the ajax call, and then change the line in the success to `$(form_element).slideUp(1000);`) or you can add a line to ajax call arguments `context: this,`.

Answer (score 0):

just change the selector. `id` attribute must be unique in html

```
$("[name='form']").submit(function() {
    $this = $(this);    
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        cache: false,       
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('#loading').show();
            $('#result').hide();
        },
        success: function(data) {
            if(data==1){
              $('#loading').hide();
              $('#result').fadeIn('slow').html("ok");
              $('#result').addClass('true');
              $this.slideUp(1000);
            }
        else {
            $('#loading').hide();
            $('#result').fadeIn('slow').html(data);
            $('#result').addClass('errors');
        }}
    });
     e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Updated! after each textarea. your code not remove/slideup. in your code only remove top one line so after not remove. ex in my code : remove 'id=42'.

Answer (score -1):

use Jquery `.each()` method:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#forms').each(function() {

       this.submit(function() {
           $.ajax({ ... });
       });
    });

})
```