# I have an error while passing post parameters using AJAX and Symfony 3.x

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, symfony

I want to use Ajax to past POST parameters in one of my controller.

For this, i did this code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('navbar').style.visibility='hidden';

idacc = $("#idAcc").data();
console.log(idacc);
var form = $("#form");
div = form.find("div");
console.log(div);
$("#ajax").click(function(div){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/message/add/" + {{ id }},
            data: div,
            success: function(div){
                console.log(div);
                console.log($(this));
            }
        });
    console.log("click");
});
</script>
```

It's a little script that i've made while i was searching in the web.

My html struct is :

```
<div class="form>
    <div>...</div>
    <div>...</div>
    <div>...</div>
    <div>...</div>
    .....
</div>
```

So with my script, the div variable receive all of the div in the div with the "form" class. It's ok when i dump it in the success function, i have what i want. But when I see in the symfony toolbar POST parameters, there's nothing, i tried to do this as well :

```
data: { 'div': div }
```

I'm getting an error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaultView' of undefined

Comment: How are you setting `id` here `{{ id }}`

Comment: @JayBlanchard I'm passing the id parameters in the controllers. The id is okay, it shows what I want.

Comment: You shouldn’t hard-code your route: `url: "{{ path('message_add', {id: id}) }}"`, something like that.

Comment: Remove this line `console.log($(this));` `$(this)` is likely not what you think it is.

Comment: @COil Thanks man, it's better like this. But doesn't fix my problem ! But thanks for the tip !

Comment: @JayBlanchard Yeah, sorry i paste this line but this one is not anymore in my code, i was just trying to know what is it.

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936211/jquery-cannot-read-property-defaultview-of-undefined-error

Comment: @COil I saw this before, but i tried to add data: <code>{'div': $(this).div } </code> But i think i'm not using this right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If used twig construction `{{ id }}`, you must sure what your Controller-Action return `'id' => 'some id'`.

I recommend for you use `{{ path() }}`

```
url: '{{ path("app.admin.search.certificate", {"cartId": cart_id}) }}',
app.admin.search.certificate - path to you route.
cartId - parameters for route and action.
```

Comment: I used it now, thanks men, but didn't solve my first problem. But thanks for the tips btw !

Comment: @Sebastien Napo, welcome. 
Try rename `div`, for example `myData`.
div - it's html tag, mb hear is problem?

Comment: Try get data this method: `data: $('#form_search_certificate').serialize(),`
#form_search_certificate - id form